# where to config database in production in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, config, production

after laravel is deployed to a server.
Somehow even I configured `root/config/database.php`

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'changed to my db name'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'changed username'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'changed password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

I changed the three fields above.  Shouldn't that the only config need to be done in order to setup the database in production?

Is there anything that I am missing about laravel 5.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to edit config file. Edit [`.env`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration) file instead:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=some_password
```

Comment: ah what I thought that's only for development purpose that's why I never thought of coming into .env thx thx a lot

Comment: you are the first to reply :D will give you the check but give me few minutes thx thx

Answer (score 1):

You can config your database detail .env in root of your project

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:n4Ecgg93Lh9YpLjCSwJG8WfgxlHjJ/aFOZkR0efXm0M=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE= 'DB NAME'
DB_USERNAME='USER NAME
DB_PASSWORD='PASSWORD'

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the database name in **.env** file

After installing Laravel is set your application key to a random string. If you installed Laravel via Composer or the Laravel installer, this key has already been set for you. In **.env** file you will find this key. Also you will find DB_DATABASE where you can set the name of your database.